# Validation list with label

Tags: google-sheets

I am using data in sheet `Jobs` as a reference to validate a field in `Sheet 1`. The data in `Jobs` is:

```
Job Name                    Job Number
--------------------------------------------------------
Site Internal Development   WS-2013-0001
Client Website              WS-2013-0002
```

So the field in sheet one needs to show `Job Number`. It does, but the problem is, when you get to several hundred Job numbers, you are not sure which one you are choosing without going to the `Jobs` sheet.

Any way, when a field is clicked, that it could list the JN and the Job Description?

So instead of just showing `WS-2013-0001` it would show `WS-2013-0001 - Site Internal Development` but once clicked only show `WS-2013-0001`.

Maybe Validation is the wrong way to do this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think anything like that is possible. It seems you actually want a custom-built web application, not just a spreadsheet - even though Google Spreadsheets *are* powerful.

Answer (score 1):

A compromise might be to lookup the description for the value (once chosen) in an adjacent cell (so an obvious wrong selection is readily apparent and can immediately be corrected) or to include both elements in the validation and, separately, strip out the description (keep the code), perhaps with a script.